# SQL Query between date with more criteria (VBA Excel - Acess)

Tags: date, criteria, between

first post here. I learn excel vba by myself and I have a doubt I think u guys can help me. I have a sql query that searchs my database (Access) Between two dates.

`SQL = "Select * From Financeiro Where Data Between #" & Format(Range("DB_Financeiro_DataInicial"), "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# and #" & Format(Range("DB_Financeiro_DataFinal"), "MM/DD/YYYY") & "#" & "Order By Data"`

But I want to add another criteria in this same line code, for example, I want to search specifics vet names in my database between to dates. Can u guys help me to do it? Since I've been learning by myself in 7 months, there are some things that I don't know how to fix yet.

'Financeiro' is my database in access, since i'm brazilian, it's in portuguese.
'DB_Financeiro_Data' is a named cell in my sheet that receives the date information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "AND":

```vb
SQL = "Select * From Financeiro Where Data Between #" & Format(Range("DB_Financeiro_DataInicial"), "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# and #" & Format(Range("DB_Financeiro_DataFinal"), "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# AND VetName Like '%" & Range("DB_Financeiro_Pesquisa") & "%' Order By Data;"
```

Comment: That worked really well, thank you man, that helped me a lot!!

Comment: No probs. Don't forget to click the grey tick under the vote numbers to turn it green if it's the answer to your problem, and upvote an answer (plus any others) if you found them useful

Comment: I was trying to find something like that, clicked right now, thank you so much!